# "I'm not taking a Knut under twenty." meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "Venomous Tentacula seeds," said George. "We need them for the Skiving Snackboxes but they're a Class C Non-Tradeable Substance so we've been having a bit of trouble getting hold of them."
>
> "Ten Galleons the lot, then, Dung?" said Fred.
>
> "Wiv all the trouble I went to to get 'em?" said Mundungus, his saggy, bloodshot eyes stretching even wider. "I'm sorry, lads, but **I'm not taking a Knut under twenty**."
>
> "Dung likes his little joke," Fred said to Harry.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Pheonix</sub>

I think "I'm not taking a Knut under twenty" here means *I would only accept your money if you paid me above twenty Galleons*. But I'm not sure if my understanding is correct. Does the sentence content any idiom?

Comment: From [this wikibooks guide to Harry Potter/Magic/Money](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Muggles%27_Guide_to_Harry_Potter/Magic/Money) *- Wizarding money comes in three denominations: bronze Knuts, silver Sickles, and golden Galleons. There are 29 Knuts in one Sickle, and 17 Sickles make up a Galleon.* The standard idiom that JK Rowling is riffing off here is [*(I) won't take a **penny** under (my stated minimum price).*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22won%27t+take+a+penny+under%22)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your understanding of the sentence is correct. In Harry Potter, a Knut is the smallest form of currency. When Mundungus says "I'm not taking a Knut under twenty [Galleons]", he does mean that he will go absolutely no lower than 20 Galleons.

It's the same as saying "I want 20 dollars and not a penny less," just with fictional currency instead of a real one.

Answer (score 3):

It's an inclusive range, not an exclusive one. "A Knut under twenty" means 20 Galleons minus a Knut. Thus it means that he will not accept 19.99 Galleons (I forget how much a Knut comes to exactly, but it's essentially the penny of the wizarding world); the minimum price he will accept is 20 Galleons.

It's not an idiom; the words are all literal.